# QGIS android issues with editing points on lines and polygons

Tags: qgis, editing, android

I am using QGIS on an android tablet and cannot delete mistaken points in a line or polygon. Does anyone know how to do this?

I also have an issue with the first point of a line/polygons starting not where I put the first tap when I start a polygon, but where the last point was on the previous polygon - resulting in the first section being incorrect. How to get around this issue?